# How do I turn off Identifiergeneration in fluent nhibernate when using automapping

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I use NHibernate 3.0 with fluent configuration. I automap my persistent model like this:

```
AutoMap
    .AssemblyOf<BaseEntity>()
    .Where(type => type.Namespace != null && type.Namespace.Contains("PersistendModel"))
```

This works fine, but I don't want to use the default identifierGenerators. My objects have initialized GUID Id's, but as it stands now they are overwritten by NHibernate.

What do i need to add (Convention, Override, SomeThingElse?), so this will not happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the following convention:

```
public class IdConvention : IIdConvention
{

    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    }

}
```

this does the trick for all my persisted classes in one go.